# What is the word for the wrongdoing that one committed to do another person great harm thus it caused grudge of another?

Tags: single-word-requests

I've been searching for a word (noun) that describes the wrongdoing that one was aware to commit consequentially causing great damage to someone who thus developed a sense of grudge, likely leading to the victim's vengeance.

The emphasis is on **the heinous misdeed** conducted by someone against who the victim holds strong resentment and eagerness to revenge himself on.

Like the reason for Hamlet to kill his uncle. Or the past event that caused generations of mutual enmity between the two clans of Romeo and Juliet.

Here's the samples to show how I would use this word:

> It's unforgivable that the burglar murdered Peter Parker's uncle, as a hero he must seek retribution for such ____ .

> All the members of this clan have been plotting a vengeance on the bandit group which kidnapped an unmarried daughter from them a week ago. This is a highest level of ____ especially when it happened to a prestigious local clan, they would not forgive or forget what the bandits had done .

I have looked up a few words, including crime, misconduct, iniquity. But none of them could describe the combined meaning of "**immoral conduct out of one's ill-intention** that **severely harmed another**, while **possibly but not necessarily resulting in a vengeance** by the victim **out of grudge**."

Can you help me with this single word question?

I have looked up the collocations of **iniquity** in COCA, and yes it's very close though it still lacks the precise definition I want.

Comment: I see no problem with _iniquity_ whatever. It might be your best bet.

Comment: A likely term here is ***assault*** (as in ***assault & battery***, but you probably wouldn't want to use ***battery*** as a standalone term with that sense).

Comment: Do you mean specifically something which causes a feud/grudge and is the subject of a continued argument (like a [bone of contention](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/a-bone-of-contention)), or more generally a great wrong that might or might not cause a grudge (maybe iniquity, wrong, slight, insult...).

Comment: I doubt there is a single word that covers all your requirements (deliberate intent to harm,  resentment by victim, revenge).

Comment: How about *evil*?